# Split linux installation ISO into two parts

Tags: system-installation, iso

There a lot of guide how to split ISO file into multiple parts and merge them. But I want to split Linux ISO file into two parts, write on two DVD disks and install that Linux.

Is it possible? How to do that?

I would like to explain why I need it. I have a HP 6730b notebook and I have to install some custom distribution of Debian. I got this distribution on pendrive and it takes about 8GB. My notebook cannot be booted form this pendrive because the BIOS has some issue and the notebook hangs. I tried to update the BIOS but HP provides BIOS update files only for Windows.

So I tried to update the BIOS according to [this](http://knarrnia.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/howto-update-you-hp-bios-from-linux/) tutorial. I get error during bios update so I cannot update bios. So now I want to install Debian from the DVD but it is too large for one DVD disk. So I have to split it on to two DVD disks.

Comment: A dual layer DVD will be large enough. However I recommend using a netinst iso, which is only a couple of hunderd MB, the rest gets downloaded online. Splitting an existing install iso is not trivial, you have to manipulate the contents and indexes.

Comment: What is this custom distribution? Can't you just install a normal, minimal Debian and then add whatever extra packages you need? Why does this thing need 8GB of image!?

Comment: I don't know why this need 8GB. It is special distribution for special purpose and I got this from vendor. Now I am burning dual layer 8GB DVD.

Comment: Is installing the base system, then using the internet to download and install everything else via `apt-get` an option?

Comment: I think that there is not that option. This debian does not use any public apt repository. It has its own drivers and configuration. I burned dula layer 8GB DVD and it also does not work so my notebook causes the issue. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would investigate is if you can cut down your custom distribution to fit on one DVD and install the rest from the net.

If that would not work (no network), just keep track of the `.deb` packages you remove to size down and copy those to second DVD, and install them from there using `dpkg`.

Comment: I don't know what I can cut. I used `find ./ -name '*.deb'` command to find locations of deb files and all deb files are in pool directory which takes only 470MB. So I have to remove sth else.

Comment: @Mariusz Is this a live system, not for installing? It seems a bit excessive to have 7.5Gb for that

Comment: It is not a live system. It is for installing. I burned dual layer DVD and my notebook hangs during booting. I tested pendrive and DVD on another PC and both works correctly. So my notebook causes the issue.